# How can I change & display particular fields in an array in a mongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I change & display particular fields in an array in a mongoDB document? I have a field like this:

```
   "mainField_e": {
       "routesArr_e": [
           {
               "eField_a": {
                   "field_a1": 8197,
                   "field_a2": "a string"
               },
               "field_b": "b string"
           }, ..
       ]
   }
```

..and I want this:

```
   "routesArr_e": [
       {
           "field_a1": 8197,
           "field_a2": "a string",
           "field_b": "b string"
       }, ..
   ]
```

I tried the following command:

```
   db.coll.aggregate([
       {
           $addFields: { 
               "routesArr_e.field_a1": "$mainField_e.routesArr_e.eField_a.field_a1",
               "routesArr_e.field_a2": "$mainField_e.routesArr_e.eField_a.field_a2",
               "routesArr_e.field_b": "$mainField_e.routesArr_e.field_b"
           }
       }, {
           $project: {
               "routesArr_e": 1
           }
       }
   ]).pretty();
```

However this puts individual fields into outputs:

```
   "routesArr_e": {
       "field_a1": [8197, 6873, ..],
       "field_a2": ["a string", "different string", ..],
       "field_b": ["b string", "another string", ..]
   }
```

..rather than keeping `routesArr_e` as an array with fields

I really need some guidance because I've tried a number of combinations of `$addFields` and `$project` but cannot get this right. Many thanks

Comment: Try [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

Comment: @thammada.ts I have played with this but an example based on the data above would be useful. With thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to get to your desired output.

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    _id: false, // if you want to remove _id
    routesArr_e: {
      $map: {
        input: "$mainField_e.routesArr_e",
        in: {
          field_a1: "$$this.eField_a.field_a1",
          field_a2: "$$this.eField_a.field_a2",
          field_b: "$$this.field_b"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bPisuWCgA2h)

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: Simple solution & really useful mongo link!